# CoreData Memory management issue

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode, core-data

I'm using Coredata and have a Data Model with the following toMany relationships:

> Rooms.isUsedBy -> Class        many classes use a Room
>   Class.hasStudents -> Students  many Students are in a Class

Given the Room I want to get all of the students that use the room.
Here is the simplified code:

```
-(void) studentsinRoom:(Room*)aRoom {
    NSSet* roomStudents = [[NSSet alloc]init];
    for (SchoolClass* aClass in aRoom.isUsedBy) {
        roomStudents = [roomStudents setByAddingObjectsFromSet:aClass.hasStudents];
    }
    [roomStudents release];
}
```

roomStudents is computed correctly.
However when exiting the method I get a “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” error.

I'm debuggin this in the iPhone Simulator.

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing/not doing something correctly with the memory management.
I do have a break set on "malloc_error_break" and it is not being hit.

Comment: Is roomStudenta a NSManagedObject?

Comment: O nevermind the code block is confusing try using the insert codeblock feature

Answer (score 1):

Change it to something like:

```
- (void) studentsinRoom:(Room*)aRoom
{
    NSSet* roomStudents = nil;
    for (SchoolClass* aClass in aRoom.isUsedBy)
    {
        roomStudents = [roomStudents setByAddingObjectsFromSet:aClass.hasStudents];
    } 
}
```

The setByAddingObjectsFromSet: method returns an auto-released NSSet object, so you don't want to release it yourself. You're getting the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when the autorelease pool is drained and the object you already released is released a second time.

Just as a side note, the name `hasStudents` seems confusing, it sounds like it would be a boolean - I think just `students` would make the code easier to read for that to-many relationship.

Comment: First time user, next time will use code block feature, thanks for the help.  hasStudents comes from entity relationship diagrams and is pretty common in that world.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with Key-Value coding. For example:

`roomStudents = [aRoom valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.isUsedBy.hasStudents"];`

See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176) for more.

Comment: IMHO this is a better answer than the first though they both work. One minor problem the code should be:
[aRoom valueForKeyPath:@"isUsedBy.@distinctUnionOfSets.hasStudents"];